# how to add the column names to the input dataset using R script in Machine Learning model

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to add the column names to the input dataset using below R script.

```
dataset1 <- maml.mapInputPort(1)#class: data.frame
# Sample operation
cols <- c("age",
    "workclass",
    "fnlwgt",
    "education",
    "education-num",
    "marital-status",
    "occupation",
    "relationship",
    "race",
    "sex",
    "capital-gain",
    "capital-loss",
    "hours-per-week",
    "native-country",
    "income")
 colnames(data.frame) <- cols
 data.set = dataset1;
 maml.mapOutputPort("data.set");
```

But I am getting the error like below figure.

[image]

Can you please tell me how to add the column names to the input dataset using R script in Machine Learning model?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved my issue to add column names to input data set using below R script.

```
dataset1 <- maml.mapInputPort(1)#class: data.frame
# Sample operation
cols <- c("age",
"workclass",
"fnlwgt",
"education",
"education-num",
"marital-status",
"occupation",
"relationship",
"race",
"sex",
"capital-gain",
"capital-loss",
"hours-per-week",
"native-country",
"income")
colnames(dataset) <- cols
data.set = dataset1;
maml.mapOutputPort("data.set");
```

Earlier, I did mistake in this line
`colnames(data.frame)<-cols`

Now I am updating above line with the this line of code `colnames(dataset) <- cols`

Answer (score 0):

I think that must be `dataset1` instead of `dataset`.

```
dataset1 <- maml.mapInputPort(1) #class: data.frame

# Sample operation

cols <- c("age",
    "workclass",
    "fnlwgt",
    "education",
    "education-num",
    "marital-status",
    "occupation",
    "relationship",
    "race",
    "sex",
    "capital-gain",
    "capital-loss",
    "hours-per-week",
    "native-country",
    "income")

colnames(dataset1) <- cols

maml.mapOutputPort("dataset1");
```

You must have consistency in naming your dataset / declaring your variable. Sometimes it is my mistake too, when using R scripts.